# How would I select all anchor links in .main-nav that do not have the href set to #

Tags: jquery

Right now I'm selecting all anchor links in .main-nav and then loggin them in the console. I'd like to exclude links with the href set to #. This is what I have so far, not sure how to exclude what I want...

```
$(".main-nav a").each(function(){
        var navlinks =  $(this).attr("href");
        console.log(navlinks);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".main-nav a[href!='#']").each(function(){
        var navlinks =  $(this).attr("href");
        console.log(navlinks);
});
```

[`jquery attribute selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/s3wnb/1/

Comment: Awesome, thats what I was lookin for. I was trying to use :not for some reason and couldnt get that to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.main-nav a[href!="#"]').each(function(){
        var navlinks =  $(this).attr("href");
        console.log(navlinks);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e5HPV/

Jquery Api Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/